# update int value to mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, int

I have a `text` input field that has a `type=number`.When i post it from the form containing this element to the `saveform.php` it recieves the numbers in the form of string.So when i use  the update query in `saveform.php` to update the db with this value , `mysql` gets updated with the `intval` of this string.In `mysql` i have a column by the name `mobile_no` which is of the type `int` and of length `15`.

*saveform.php*

```
 $query="UPDATE `registered_users` SET `user_name`=?,`mobile_no`=?,`addressline1`=?,`addressline2`=?,`city`=?,`zipcode`=? WHERE `user_email`=?";
 $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
 $statement->bind_param("sisssis", $username, $mobileno, $addressline1, $addressline2, $city, $zipcode, $email);
```

This is the code of the query that i have made.I have made a `var_dump` of the `$mobile_no` and the output of this dump is given below.

```
string '9560987629' (length=10)
```

This gets updated in the db with this 
    int `2147483647` .How am i supposed to update the right values without changing my `mysql` column from int to string.

Comment: Make it a bigint. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html

Comment: mobile phone nnumbers can contain characters like `+` before the country code. It might be better to make it some form of text column instead of a number

Comment: You may actually want to consider storing phone #s as strings instead of ints. A quick search on SO shows several reasons for using a string data type in this case.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks it worked.

Comment: Phone numbers aren't numeric data, they're string data.  You're storing the value incorrectly in the first place.

Comment: So i should use string as the datatype to store phone no? @David

Comment: @NahidSuhail: Yes.  A phone number is a string.  By coincidence alone that string generally contains number characters, but it's still a string.  I can't imagine any scenario where you'd ever need to *perform math* on a phone number.

Comment: Also `zipcode` should be a string, not an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `2147483647` is actually the highest value a signed integer can have.
You need to change the datatype to bigint, then it will allow for large enough numbers.

I would recommend that you store phone numbers as strings though. Depending on the use case, it could be necessary at some point. Some countries actually operate with phone numbers starting with 0. At that point your best bet is to store the numbers as a string.

[Why is  2,147,483,647 the max int value?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2124366?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that the maximum value for an integer column is `2147483647` or `4294967295` if unsigned. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html

You should use a `bigint` data type to store integers larger than those values.

You probably shouldn't store the phone numbers as integers though. Phone numbers, and zip codes, although formatted as numbers, aren't actually numbers. I recommend storing them as strings.

For example my zip code `02128` if stored in an integer column would be `2128`.